# JavaScript/jQuery: Select on change event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this problem trying to getting one single function attach multiple individual functions on "Change" event of a `dropdown` list using `for ... in` loop. The `$('select')` object top has no method `'on'` is the Type error detected by Chrome Debugger.

Here is my code: (I don't have much JavaScript / jQuery knowledge so please be bear up with my coding)

```
function AKaizerDropdown(HiddenFeild) {     //#id of hidden field passed as parameter
var select = $('select'); // select object assigned to variable
var selectcount = 0;
var Selecthold=new Array();

for (select in this) {

    select.on('change', function() {
        var SelectedIndex = this.attr('selectedIndex');
        selecthold[selectcount] = [select.attr('id'), selectedindex];         
        //Select ID and Selected index assigned as an array into Selecthold Array element
    });

    selectcount +=1; 

}
var item= new array();

//Elements in selecthold array printed onto hidden field 
for (item in selecthold) {
    $(HiddenFeild).val += item[0] + item[1]; //Assigns values to element Hiddenfield in DOM
}

}
```

Edited Code :

```
 $.fn.AKaizerDropdown = function (HiddenFeild) {

var select_ = $(this).find('select'); 
var selectcount = 0;
var Selecthold=new Array();

select_.each(function () {

    $(this).on('change', function () { //everything runs fine except dropdownlist doesn't enter into this event when an item is chosen
        var SelectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
        Selecthold[selectcount] = [this.id, Selectedindex];

    });

});

var button_ = $(this).find('input')
button_.on('click', function () {
    for (item in Selecthold) {
        $(HiddenFeild).val += item[0] + item[1]+','; //Assigns values to element Hiddenfeild in DOM seperated by ","
    }
});
```

}

**Somewhat fixed code still doesn't work**

Here is the part where i attach it to popover Bootstrap(twitter 2.3.2) .

```
//think the problem lies here where the pop up seems to re-render the same same html found in ($#KaizerDragon") where all JavaScript is probably discarded?

$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_ADragonTreeviewt41").popover({
    html: true, container: 'body',
    trigger: 'click',
    content: function () {

        $(function () {
            $("#KaizerDragon").AKaizerDropdown();
        });
        return $("#KaizerDragon").html();

    }
```

});

So my question is how can I correct the above code to get the intended output(as in comments within code) ?

Comment: jquery version used and what is the value you are expecting to assign to the hidden field

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: @ Arun PJhony & Andri ver 1.10.2 Jquerry Used,

 Im expecting to print out the values in selecthold array containing ID of select element and then the selected index of the respective element ID (I probably might have to add some spectator Symbols in the hidden feild values )

Comment: this has no method attr `this.attr('selectedIndex');` i think you meant select

Comment: I've never heard of jquerry. Is it a variant of jQuery where it isn't `$()`, but `rrrrrrrrrr()`?

Comment: @ jay harris i belive it does have that attribute i picked it up from some question asked here but anyway here is a referance :
 http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp

Comment: @ Dude Spell nazi Detected !

Comment: @ jay harris , im only asking this because i dont know much about javascript doesnt "this" keyword become or refer to "select" when it is an innerfunction  , since it is the object calling the function ?

Usually in other languages that is the case so i assumed it to be the same here .. was i wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring

```
var select = $('select'); // select object assigned to variable
```

But then overriding the value in your for loop

```
for (select in this) ...
```

That is to say, the `select` inside the loop isn't the same as you declared above.

Comment: o.O i dont get how its overriding doesn't the loop tell the compiler to look for each 'select ' element inside a particular element ?

Comment: First, `this` has the context of your function, not your jQuery object. Secondly, the `in` keyword is used to enumerate over the properties of an object. The select variable inside the function is not a property. But that's not how you want to do it anyway. Try `select.each(function(){ $(this).on('change', function() { /* your callback code*/ }) });`

Comment: hey thanx, i didnt realise that " var  select = $('select');" returned an array object instead of a single object , which didnt make much sense when used in the for.. in loop so i fixed it in the original Post, but it still dosent work :S

Comment: i hAve explained what part dosent work in the fixed code as comments

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
            select.each(function(){
                 $(this).on('change', function() {
                    var SelectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
                    Selecthold[selectcount] = [this.id, SelectedIndex];         
                    //Select ID and Selected index assigned as an array into Selecthold Array element
                });

            })
```

Comment: thanx , i edited original post but still dosent make the on change event trigger

Comment: nope still wont , it dosent getinto the onchange event when i click on he dropdownlist, (@least thats what the chrome debugger says)

Comment: just console.log(select_) variable see what you get

Comment: 1 tags failed to render in 30000 ms gives that error when i select an item on drop downlist

Comment: still dosent seem to work, i think the last part is where the problem lies but i have no idea how to correct it or i might mess up the other popups trying to alter the default pop up jscript ?